# How to pass data from onBindViewHolder inside Adapter to Tab

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

My app uses Tabs. How can i pass data from adapter of Tab 3 to Tab 1.
The Tabs use viewPager.

When i click an items on Tab 3, it opens Tab 1 using viewPager.setCurrentItem(0). How can i pass data to Tab 1 as i open it.

example; In opeing a fragment from another fragment, you use Bundle. How to do same with Tabs.

```
Tab 3 Adapter code

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    final VendorHolder vendorHolder = list.get(position);       
    viewHolder.shoeName.setText(vendorHolder.getName());


    viewHolder.vendorName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int shoeID =  position;

       //Data i want to pass
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("data1", "data");
                bundle.putString("dataType", "Type1");

final ViewPager viewPager = MainActivity.myViewpager; 
//Instance of viewpager in MainActivity
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

   }
  });

 }


Inside Tab 1 
//Receive data here
```

In Tab 1, receive "data1" and "dataType"

Assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to create interface to transfer Data one activity or fragment to another activity or fragment.

Just like this:

```
public interface ClickListner {
void onClick(int position, int id);
```

}

register into Adapter :-

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private ClickListner clickListner;

MyAdapter(ClickListner clickListner){
this.clickListner = clickListner;
}

onBindViewHolder{

    holder.text.setOnClickListener(v -> clickListner.onClick(position, allLeadModelList.get(position).getId()));

}
```

}

and Activity or Fragment side code :

```
public class AllLeadsFragment extends Fragment implements ClickListner {

onCreateview(){

myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this::onClick);

}

@Override
public void onClick(int position, int id) {

}
```

}

You finally get your click listerner value in onClick()